# Converter Script AutoHotkey para C# ou VB6

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6, autohotkey

Gostaria de converter o seguinte `script` feito com `AutoHokey`:

```
DllCall("shdocvw\SetShellOfflineState", "int", False)
```

Com esse `script` consigo "tirar" o `Internet Explorer` do modo `offline` sem intervenção do usuário. Esse procedimento é necessário pois quando o `IE` está `offline` causa erro em um componente de terceiro que estou utilizando.

Outras sugestões para o executar o procedimento também são bem vindas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [AutoHotkey.Interop](https://github.com/amazing-andrew/AutoHotkey.Interop) para funcionar no C#.

O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
public class AutoHotKey
{
    private readonly AutoHotkeyEngine _ahkEgine = new AutoHotkeyEngine();
    private const string comando = @"DllCall(""shdocvw\SetShellOfflineState"", ""int"", False)"; //aqui fica o script.

    public AutoHotKey()
    {
        _ahkEngine.ExecRaw(comando);
    }
}
```

Tambem tem [este link](http://irisclasson.com/2015/01/06/using-autohotkey-dll-with-c-in-a-wpf-application/), que demonstra como utilizar em WPF, e alguns exemplos mais completos.

Comment: Excelente, obrigado!